# MVC in Java: How to open 2nd view upon user selection?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

According to [this](http://austintek.com/mvc/) tutorial I implemented the MVC design pattern in Java. It seemed very simple and without giving it too much thought our group started programming.
We have 4 packages Model, View, Controller, and Main. The Main package has only a class Main.java that joins all packages so to speak.

To simplify it: We have 3 views, 3 controllers and 1 model (and 1 main)

```
SelectingOpponentView.java
SelectingOpponentController.java

GridView.java
GridController.java

NetworkSearchView.java
NetworkSearchController.java

Model.java

Main.java
```

The way we set it up is: Buttons in every view have an ActionListener. The ActionListener event is sent to the according controller class and there the event is handled. This requires of course that our Main.java class sets everything up, i.e. the controller needs to learn about view and model and view needs to learn about controller.

The goal is to first show SelectingOpponentView then let the user choose either to open GridView or NetworkSearchView.
My question is now, how do I open the 2nd view according to the user's input AND make the necessary connections for MVC to work? Is it possible to "wait" in Main.java until the user has made his choice?

It may be that we didn't implement MVC right, and therefore need to make some structural changes even.

Comment: `"Is it possible to "wait" in Main.java until the user has made his choice?"` -- There's no need as you're using an **event-driven** GUI library, and so you already have your control responding to **events**, and this is as it should be. The behavior that the events elicit within the control will depend on the state of the model.

Comment: I see. I took your hint and thought about it more, the solution was simple. Thanks.